# eslint treat my *.ts files as javascript in a project that also has vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I'm working on a web project with typescript and vue. After reading the docs for both [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/) and [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/), I've settled with the following eslint configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "prettier",
  ],
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    extraFileExtensions: [".vue"],
  },
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
};
```

My vue files are correctly parsed, but my ts files have unreasonable lint errors. It appears they are linted for javascript syntax. Like in the image below:

[image]

If I remove `parserOptions` and change the parser to `@typescript-eslint/parser`, the ts files are correctly linted, but lint for vue files breaks.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm too tired or too old, anyway, the problem was in having two `parserOptions` sections in the same lint file. Here is the final working version:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "prettier",
  ],
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
    extraFileExtensions: [".vue"],
  },
//  parserOptions: {
//    ecmaVersion: "latest",
//    sourceType: "module",
//  },
  plugins: ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have two options :

1. change `parser: "vue-eslint-parser"` to `@typescript-eslint/parser`
2. add an override for .ts files and there set the parser to `@typescript-eslint/parser`

Comment: I'm sorry for your trouble @Hindicator. After a break, I just spotted I had two parserOptions sections in the file. Thanks for your time.